# Lambda не добавляет данные в mongodb EC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lambda, amazon-web-services

у меня есть API работающее на aws lambda  и api gateway. На локальном хосте и тестовой базе данных(mlab) всё работает отлично. Но когда деплою на амазон мой API не может добавить данные в mongodb которая на ec2. У нас открыты все разрешения и lambda и mongodb находятся на одном vpc.

Вот мой код :

```
 MongoClient.connect(dbURL, {useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, db){

          if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error: ', err);
          } else {
            console.log('Connection established to ', dbURL);
          }
          let myDB = db.db('iyc')

        let arr = [];

          locations.forEach(element => {
            let insertData = {};
            insertData.user_id = req.body.user_id;
            insertData.device_id = req.body.device_id;
            insertData.app_type = req.body.app_type;
            insertData.datetime = JSON.parse(element.datetime)/1000;
            insertData.latitude = element.latitude;
            insertData.longitude = element.longitude;
            insertData.address = element.address;
            insertData.method = element.method;
            insertData.accuracy = element.accuracy;
            insertData.status = element.status;
            insertData.confidence = element.confidence
           arr.push(insertData)
          }) 

          try {
            myDB.collection('userdevices').insertMany(arr, function(err, data) {
              if(err) {
                console.log("Insert db err " + err)
              } else if(!data) {
                console.log('No data has been inserted')
              }

            })
           }
          catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
          }
          db.close();
        })
```

Comment: Не понимаю, причем тут стрелочные функции, когда речь о базе данных? Смотрите, что выводит в ошибках. А стрелочные функции - это лишь особенность языка `JavaScript`, не более.

Comment: Что в итоге выводит Lambda? (Можно посмотреть в CloudWatch). Какие имеено "все" разрешения открыты, какова конфигурация sercurity group?

Comment: Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error: { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [172.31.102.145:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to 172.31.102.145:27017 timed out] лог из cloudwatch. Сисадмин говорит что открыл мне permission-ы чтобы у меня был аксесс к дб

Comment: По ошибке вы ловите `timeout` на коннекте, может быть БД нагружена, или не туда коннектетесь?

Comment: Проверяли хост порт юзернейм и пароль . БД тоже работает не нагружено так как это наш тестовый(qa)